# Do I need to close socket before re-accepting connection?

Tags: linux, sockets

I am trying to automatically re-establish connection if for some reason the connection is dropped. Do I need to close a connected socket before I can accept another connection? The following is the code.

```
int inbound_socket_thread(void * arg)
{
   int state = INACTIVE;
   sockfd = socket(...)
   // bind sockfd to an addr
   // listen (sockfd, 3)

   while(1)
   {
      switch(state)
      {
         case INACTIVE:
            connectedFd = accept(sockfd, ...)
            ...
            state = ACTIVE;
            break;

         case ACTIVE:
            size = recv(connectedFd, ...)
            if (size > 0)
            { // do something }
            else
               state = CLOSE;

            break;

         case CLOSE:
            close(connectedFd); //<- is this necessary?
            state = INACTIVE;
            break;
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you must close an opened socket before accept another connection.